# Scientific paper usage: "It has been shown, ..." or "It was shown, ..."?

Tags: past-tense

If something has been discovered in 1980 and I want to refer to this discovery in a scientific text, how would I do this?

> It has been shown, ...

or

> It was shown, ...

and especially: Why is one form used over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shown is used here in the sense of having been demonstrated, explained, proven, or confirmed.

- It ***was*** shown... [[simple past tense or *indicative* preterite](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-to%20be.html)]
- It ***has been*** shown... [[present perfect tense](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-to%20show.html)]

[The difference](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-simple-past-and-present-perfect/2752310.html) in usage between *simple past tense* and *present perfect tense*, is that while both refer to an action that was finished in the past, there is one important difference: simple past tense indicates that something occurred at a *specific time* in the past, whereas present perfect tense suggests that something occurred at an *unknown time* in the past.

Furthermore, ***present perfect tense*** is used to stress the *present importance* of a past event, while the exact time it occurred is relatively unimportant.

So in the ***simple past tense*** phrasing of your sentence, you're simply indicating that something was shown at a specific time in the past: *It was shown...*

But in the ***present perfect tense*** form, you're signalling the current importance of something that was shown **at some time in the past which is either unspecified or irrelevant** to the main point of your statement: *It has been shown...*

Comment: Yes, except that the use of the past (simple or present says nothing about the specific time of the event beyond its being in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Both "simple past" and "present perfect"  can be used to refer to finished actions, but there is a slight difference between them.

We use present perfect to show a finished action **which has a result in the present or still is very important and significant**, so when you want to use it in your sentence first make sure that the discovery has a result and effect in the present.

Let me clarify it with simple examples:

> I have lost my keys(the result: I can not get into my house)
>
> I have washed the dishes(the result: the dishes are clean now)

Discoveries usually have results and effects in the present and they are important as well, so I think it is better to use present perfect tense.

Simple past is used to refer to an action which finished in the past, but there is no special result for that action, in the present.

**note: the difference I mentioned is in the British English grammar.In American English, "simple past" and "present perfect" can be used interchangeably (in this special use)**

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple rule.  Ask yourself the question:  “Am I mentioning this discovery of 1980 as part of an historical study, or as a live consideration in some current investigation?”.

Greenbaum [Oxford English Grammar - OUP 1976] explains the difference between the ***simple Past*** and the ***Present Perfect*** in terms of what he calls *perspective* of the speaker/writer.

“The simple past is primarily used when the situation was completed before the time of writing.” [OEG 5.21].  “The present perfect”, he says [OEG 5.27] “... refers to a state that began before the time of speaking or writing and continues until that time.”

The simplest answer would be to use the simple past “...was shown ...”.

*The discovery of the lithium ion in 1980* led to the rapid improvements in battery technology.*

But if you were now working in this field on a topic directly descended from Goodenough’s publication, you could say that it “has led to the rapid improvements in battery technology (that still continue today)”.

I think you could write either:  “In Goodenough’s discovery of 1980 it **was** shown that ....”, or “In G’s discovery of 1980 it has been shown that...”.

Whether you pick the first or the second alternative depends on **your perspective**.  If you are seeing it as a piece of historical background to your work but is in the past, then use *was*.  If it is an important starting point for your own work and in some sense still *active* in it, then use *has been*.

But it is a moot point.  Others could disagree with me.